# Find a factorable cubic polynomial with given conditions

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I want to write a factorable cubic polynomial in the form $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$ where $-D = 42C$. $A, B, C,$ and $D$ should be nonzero integers. Is this possible?

Comment: Factorable over what field?

Comment: Factorable with integers

Comment: What are your constraints? Because I assume the solution $A=1$, $B=C=D=0$ isn't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $(x-2)(x+3)(x+7)$ works. We have $C=1$ and $D=-42$.

Added: OP asked in a comment whether one could make the roots positive. The answer is yes, the condition $-D=42C$ is not very constraining.

One simple example is $(x-126)^3$. Or else, for example, let us decide to look for a polynomial with roots $r,2r,3r$. Then $-D=42C$ becomes $6r^3=(42)(11r^2)$, giving $r=77$, and polynomial $(x-77)(x-154)(x-231)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to maintain that all roots of the polynomial are positive?

Comment: You are welcome. I will think about it. I did not arrive at the example "at random," instead I looked at the "reciprocal polynomial" $Dt^3+Ct^2+Bt+A$.  Closer examination may produce an example with positive roots.

Comment: @Vasting: I added a couple of examples with positive roots, not small, but structurally simple.

Comment: How do reciprocal polynomials play into this?

Comment: @Vasting: That's how I found the first example, the sum of the reciprocal roots was a little easier to handle that the sum $ab+bc+ca$. But then I found a simpler way.